# Transfer Foxpro Database To SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, foxpro, database-migration

How to Transfer Foxpro Database To SQL Server ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the upsize wizard, see here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129847

Comment: What if you're not fortunate enough to have a copy of foxpro?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the Sedna Upsizing Wizard Update on codeplex at http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna#SQLServerUpsizing

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving a large amount of data, I would recommend SQLXMLBulkLoad.  Doug Hennig wrote about it and has sample code at http://doughennig.blogspot.com/2006/07/sqlxmlbulkload-rocks.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you are using SQL Server, is to use a Link Server to access your VFP database without having to convert it to SQL Server.